# Is grails-plugin-log4j-2.5.1 affected by CVE-2021-44228

Tags: grails, log4j

i'm using grails-plugin-log4j-2.5.1.
I wanted to know if its affected by CVE-2021-44228.
thanks!

Comment: Affected versions are descrbed at https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=2021-44228.

Comment: This is a question for their support forums. Not something for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin itself only depends on org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j.
You need to run the dependency report and see if you have affected version on the list.
Follow this instructions: https://grails.org/blog/2021-12-14-log4j2-cve.html