# Upgrade log4j1.2.x to log4j2.17 in Grails 2.5.4

Tags: java, logging, grails, log4j, log4j2

I'm upgrading log4j dependency in my *grails 2.5.4* application from *1.2.17* to the latest version *2.17*

I've excluded log4j from the *BuildConfig.groovy* and added the following dependencies pertaining to *v2.17*:

- log4j-api
- log4j-core
- log4j-1.2-api
- log4j-slf4j-impl

I'm using the log4-1.x bridge to reduce overall codebase change. When the application boots up, I get the following exception, even though the application boots up completely.

```
Error |
java.lang.RuntimeException: Reloading agent exited via exception, please raise a jira
Error |
    at org.springsource.loaded.agent.ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.transform(ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.java:110)
Error |
    at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
Error |
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:428)
Error |
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.defineAnonymousClass(Native Method)
Error |
    at java.lang.invoke.InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.spinInnerClass(InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.java:326)
Error |
    at java.lang.invoke.InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.buildCallSite(InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.java:194)
Error |
    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(LambdaMetafactory.java:304)
Error |
    at java.lang.invoke.CallSite.makeSite(CallSite.java:302)
Error |
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkCallSiteImpl(MethodHandleNatives.java:307)
Error |
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkCallSite(MethodHandleNatives.java:297)
Error |
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil$Environment.<init>(PropertiesUtil.java:430)
Error |
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil$Environment.<init>(PropertiesUtil.java:420)
Error |
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil.<init>(PropertiesUtil.java:74)
Error |
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil.<clinit>(PropertiesUtil.java:54)
Error |
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.Constants.<clinit>(Constants.java:30)
Error |
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.createClassForProperty(AbstractLogger.java:207)
Error |
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.<clinit>(AbstractLogger.java:95)
Error |
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.<clinit>(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:35)
Error |
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<init>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:53)
Error |
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:41)
Error |
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:128)
Error |
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:107)
Error |
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:295)
Error |
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:269)
Error |
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:156)
Error |
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:132)
Error |
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:274)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.<clinit>(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:151)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.getAvailableScripts(GrailsScriptRunner.java:824)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeScriptWithCaching(GrailsScriptRunner.java:427)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.callPluginOrGrailsScript(GrailsScriptRunner.java:414)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeCommand(GrailsScriptRunner.java:378)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.main(GrailsScriptRunner.java:226)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
Error |
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.rootLoader(GrailsStarter.java:236)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.main(GrailsStarter.java:264)
Error |
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
Error |
    at org.springsource.loaded.SystemPropertyConfiguredIsReloadableTypePlugin.shouldBeMadeReloadable(SystemPropertyConfiguredIsReloadableTypePlugin.java:121)
Error |
    at org.springsource.loaded.TypeRegistry.isReloadableTypeName(TypeRegistry.java:858)
Error |
    at org.springsource.loaded.agent.SpringLoadedPreProcessor.preProcess(SpringLoadedPreProcessor.java:192)
Error |
    at org.springsource.loaded.agent.ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.transform(ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.java:107)
Error |
    ... 39 more
```

I further observed that the application is using the default logging configuration which includes:

```
org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener end
INFO: Session Metrics
```

I've configured both *log4j.properties* and *log4j2.properties* file but still it's not reading any of them.

Could someone please help me to understand where I'm going wrong.

Comment: It seems the Springloaded chokes on lambdas. Did you try disabling reloading (e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35226076/11748454))?

Comment: See comments at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70426705/upgrade-log4j-to-last-version, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70349898/how-can-we-set-a-higher-version-of-log4j-to-grails-app and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70323880/is-grails-plugin-log4j-2-5-1-affected-by-cve-2021-44228.